# matplotlib subplots_adjust - meaning of parameters

Tags: matplotlib

What are the meaning of values in [subplots_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) ?

> left  = 0.125  # the left side of the subplots of the figure

The documentation has number 0.125, etc but there is no explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values represent the distance of your subplot from the boundary of the figure. Its value is between 0 & 1. For example, if you set `top=1` the upper boundary of your subplot will coincide with the upper boundary of your figure and if you set `top=0` the upper boundary of your subplot will coincide with the lower boundary of your figure and the plot will be entirely squashed down.

It is the **percent** of figure height and figure width.

A better way to see how this works is to plot a graph and the use the option `Configure Subplots`, in the window that pops up, to adjust these values. Try this and you will able to appreciate the use of these values in a much better way.